# Is there a way for Photoshop not to force file saves on exit?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Modern code editors like VSCode or Sublime text allow their users to create new documents edit them and keep them around without forcing users to associate them with file names and saving them. These documents get autogenerated names (Untitled-1, Untitled-2, etc.).

When a user exits the editor it stores the content of these documents somewhere in their app storage area next to user settings, plugins, etc. When a user reopens the editor it preloads these documents, while showing them as not saved. From user's point of view the two processes: starting and stopping the editor and creating and saving documents are unrelated.

Adobe Photoshop on the other hand forces users to either save all new documents or discard them before exiting. The notion of these temporary documents that survive app restarts doesn't exist. I believe Photoshop behavior was the norm for all user applications 30-40 years ago, but today it's frankly annoying.

Is there a way to make Photoshop behave like a modern editor when it comes to document handling on exit?

Comment: There is a big difference though. Photoshop files can be several gigabytes if not tens of gigabytes in size text documents are like 10 kb . Theres a huge bandwidth difference there. More than that its okay to have 20 1kb files in a cache. Not so fun if you have 20 gigabytes of it.

Comment: 40 years ago I'd be happy if my computer could do more than load games from cassette :P I think the answer to this is.. 'not until Adobe make their software that way'. Though quite new to Windows, the idea of rebooting to where you left off has been a Mac paradigm for many years… yet still Adobe doesn't do it :\

Comment: text files ain't image files. Caching a bunch of text files is negligible. Caching a bunch of image files can fill a drive to capacity causing operating issues. There's a reason Photoshop doesn't randomly store content and why it asks you if things are important enough to save. Text files, for *everyone*, are small in terms of KB size. *You* may work with very small image files with Photoshop, that doesn't mean *everyone* is working with small files.

Comment: I'd be more than happy if Photoshop would do this, tbh. I have 64GB RAM & about 500GB spare space on my boot SSD [& another 12TB in the machine]. Everything else lets me reboot & returns to the exact same state afterwards, why not Ps? Even such as Final Cut Pro records the exact state at quit, no matter how big the project… so much so there is actually no Save command at all.

Comment: FCP isn't saving *actual video files* though. It's saving the equivalent of an XMP or "map" file, which is ultimately just text. It's not like FCP is saving 4GB video files when you quit the app. The *actual* video files have to be on an HDD somewhere. FCP just saves a roadmap of what you want to do with those files on the HD. Similar to how sidecar files are saved with Camera Raw in Photoshop.

Comment: @Scott - In terms of 'extra data', sure, FCP has generated minimal asset, low-qual versions & crossfades etc. - but if I've a huge Ps image open which I'm busy creating new unsaved  layers to then either my RAM or my scratch-disk will contain some essence of the whole file, re-creatable in some similar sidecar/diff style just the same way. I don't see it as an impossible task [though I'm no coder ;)

Comment: I don't think it's the same thing when you get down to pixel level editing. That's why Camera RAW, FCP, etc, *can* save sidecar files. They are editing the original file in minute ways but rather global adjustments. Sure there's a crossfade in FCP.. but all FCP need store is start and end times and the name of the effect, nothing more. It's not* generating a new video file to store for the crossfade.

Comment: @Scott - whichever way it's being done behind the scenes, the fact is it can hold it all, plus 20 history states, right there in the machine, live, whether in RAM or scratch disk. It doesn't seem too much of a leap to preserve that state at quit. Pretty much every other Mac App can do that already.

Comment: this is a software development question that has to be taken upon Adobe, not the graphic design community. We can't alter the way Photoshop behave with files.